# Madwifi VAP (and wlanconfig) modern equivalent

Tags: linux, debian, networking, wifi

It appears that the Madwifi project is deprecated, so I am curious if there is a replacement for the `wlanconfig` utility that allowed users create Virtual APs. I did search for wlanconfig in my package repositories but it seems to be gone as well

According to the [manual page](http://madwifi-project.org/users-guide/node14.html), VAPs are:

> The current MadWifi driver supports multiple APs and concurrent
>   AP/Station mode operation on the same device. The devices are
>   restricted to using the same underlying hardware, thus are limited to
>   coexisting on the same channel and using the same physical layer
>   features. Each instance of an AP or station is called a Virtual AP (or
>   VAP). Each VAP can be in either AP mode, station mode, ``special''
>   station mode, and monitor mode. Every VAP has an associated underlying
>   base device, which is created when the driver is loaded.

Essentially, I am wondering if I can get my Atheros (`ath9k`) card to act as an AP and a station at the same time...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the new 802.11 kernel drivers support this functionality under the name: Multiple Virtual Interface (vif). From [the documentation](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw/vif):

> The mac80211 subsystem in the linux kernel supports multiple wireless
>   interfaces to be created with one physical wireless card. This depends
>   on the driver implementing this. This could allow you to join multiple
>   networks at once, or connect to one network while routing traffic from
>   an access point interface.